# XORing at the address stored in EAX

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, xor

How can you XOR the value stored in EAX?

The problem is at this line:

```
xor eax, key
```

EAX contains the address of the value i want to XOR. How can I accomplish this? I though it would be something along the lines of:

```
xor [eax], key
```

but that doesn't work (syntax error)

```
 decrypt proc startAddress:DWORD , sizeOfSegment:DWORD , key:DWORD


  xor ecx, ecx    ; clear the ecx register for the counter
  mov eax, startAddress  ; copy the start address to eax
  .while ecx < sizeOfSegment  ; loop through the code
  xor eax, key    ; XOR decrypt the word
  inc eax
  inc ecx
  .endw

   ret

  decrypt endp
```

Comment: Won't help you much (and feel free to yap at me), but that'll work in nasm.  nasm is awesome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You said you're doing ...

```
xor eax, key    ; XOR decrypt the word
```

... but I'm guessing that's a typo and you're actually trying to do ...

```
xor [eax], key    ; XOR decrypt the word
```

The reason why that won't work is that `key` isn't a register: it's probably, I don't know, a synonym for something like `[ebp+4]`.

x86 (not just MASM, but nasm too: the x86 instruction set) allows register-to-register and register-to-memory and memory-to-register operands, but not memory-to-memory.

So, you need to load key into some spare register, e.g.:

```
  mov eax, startAddress
  mov ebx, key ; move key into a register, which can be XORed with [eax]
  .while ecx < sizeOfSegment
  xor [eax], ebx
```

---

On a separate matter, do you really want to do `inc eax` or should it be `add eax,4` ? I mean, you say "XOR decrypt the word": do you mean "word", or "byte", or "double-word"?